Dimension does not appear in Denavit-Hartenberg formulation
Consider the robot and Denavit-Hartenberg table in the picture below
The revolute axes of the robot intersect. Positive direction for the first revolute joint is to the right and that for the second revolute joint is upwards. Frames are assigned as in the picture where base frame is completely coincident with the first frame at the zero poisiton of the first frame (i.e when the first joint variable $\theta_1$ is 0) The distance between joints is $m$
The four Denavit-Hartenberg parameters in the table follow Craig's book $[1]$ :
$a_i$ is the distance from $Z_i$ to $Z_{i+1}$ along $X_i$
$\alpha_i$ is the angle from $Z_i$ to $Z_{i+1}$ about $X_i$
$d_i$ is the distance from $X_{i-1}$ to $X_i$ along $Z_i$
$\theta_i$ is the angle from $X_{i-1}$ to $X_i$ about $Z_i$
Denavit-Hartenberg approach does not seem to account for the distance m for that particular structure. Almost an infinite number of frame assignments are possible aside from Denavit-Hartenberg convention, for any orientation can be reached from any orientation by at most 3 rotations about local or fixed axes in space. Of course the transformations would not be as simple as those of Denavit-Hartenberg's. The dimension m can show up in many of those transformations. What I want to know is what is the correct Denavit-Hartenberg formulation for that robot to include m?
$[1]$ Craig, J. J., Introduction to Robotics, Mechanics and Control, Pearson Education International, Third edition
